# TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined --got this error while using then

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I tried the below code since node is async type inorder to run my code sequentialy I added then function, but I got the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined. I used the below code

```
    va

r arr =[]
    exceltojson({
       input: 'test.xlsx',
       output: 'test.json',// Don't need output
       sheet: 'test'
     },
     function(err, result) {
       if (err) {
         console.error(err);
       } 
    }
    )
    .then() {
      // var msg ='done';
       updateFlag();
       })

    function updateFlag(){
       console.log('end')
    }
    I expect the output like 

conversion done

    end
```

Comment: Your function should return promise for `then` to work currently it returns undefined.Please post the `exceltojson` as well

Comment: Your function should return promise for then to work --could you please share some references for this

Comment: No ,you can't see this-https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: mongoose supports promises inherently ,your library may or may not support libraries

Comment: without using promise return, is there any possibility to make this code sequential?

Comment: Please post the whole code with how you are requiring this `exceltojson` then I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you function exceltojson is not a returning a promise and this is the problem. I have converted your function into a promise. Please try the code given below.

```
function promiseExcelToJson() {
return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    exceltojson({
        input: 'test.xlsx',
        output: 'test.json',
        sheet: 'test'
      },
      function(err, result) {
         if(!err) { 
         console.log('conversion done') 
         res(result) 
        } else 
          rej(result)
      }

    )
})
}

var arr =[]
promiseExcelToJson().then(()=> {
    updateFlag();
})
function updateFlag(){
console.log('end')
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know!

Comment: Why you are wrapping a function with call back within a promise ?? .That doesn't makes sense at all

Comment: Promises are used to run callback in a synchronous way and this is the reason I am wrapping this in a promise. He is using a function in which he wants to perform something after the callback is executed.

Comment: Then why you are passing a callback function inside ?? Please explain

Comment: and why an async function ,async function inherently returns promise wrapped value,so you don't need to explicitly return a promise inside it

Comment: See, excelTOJson is a function that will eventually run a callback after it gets a result or error. Now, what the motive of the developer is to do something after that callback call is finished. A developer can also do whatever he wants to do in callback but its not a good idea to do everything in one function. So, i have made a promise that will resolve the callback and after resolving that callback we can use .then to perfrom our motive.

Comment: Please have a look here -https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise ,You need to refresh your concepts .Thanks

Comment: So, what's the problem? I am resolving a callback and making this thing synchronous so that we can use .then and perform our other functionality.

Comment: If you have some doubts then I think you should try and run this example with some function of your own that has a callback. This promise will resolve the callback and will give you the functionality of .then on this function.

Comment: @amitgupta i get what you are doing here, but why are you using the `async` keyword? even without it , it would work right. also you have to call promiseExcelToJson to get the promise back , but you are not calling it before using then

Comment: @vikrant yes you are right. I forget to call the function and i used .then without calling.

Comment: @jiss Use the updated code. I just forget to call the fucntion and i .then without calling it.

Comment: is promise the only solution?

Comment: @jiss the only way you can use `then` is with a promise.

Comment: is it possible to proceed without a response from excel to json code .. because my excel tojson and the code below(the one which I want to write inside then) that is not relatated… I just want the execution to be sequential

Comment: Yes, it's possible you can res("done") instead of resolving to result. If there is no error you can simply resolve a string of you don't want to pass the result object.

Comment: Even if it's not related you can just avoid using of the result in .then

Comment: I have some updates according to your code. You can check them.